# Proving 2 related equations are the same

Tags: algebra-precalculus, alternative-proof

I found coincidentally that these 2 existing formulas are equivalent, by using real numbers as inputs:

1. $x=1-\frac{a/c}{1-a/c}*\frac{1-b/d}{b/d}$
   and
2. $a=\frac{b/d*(1-x)}{1-b/d+b/d*(1-x)}*c$

Using output $x$ of formula 1 as input in formula 2, yields $a$ in formula 2, using the same $b$, $c$ and $d$. I was wondering if it is possible to mathematically prove these formulas are equivalent. If not, how could I state in a formal way that it is probable that these are equivalent? These simple formulas may have been used for a variety of applications already, and may be there is already some kind of proof (if yes, how could I find a source?). I am not a mathematician and my equation solving skills are very limited. I would be very pleased if someone could help. Many thanks.

Comment: Take the first equation and solve it for $a$

Comment: To ensure everyone is interpreting your fractions and such correctly, please format your equations using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/409).

Comment: First of all, set $A=a/c$ and $B=b/d$ and $y=1-x$ then write your first equation $y=\frac{A}{1-A}\frac{1-B}{B}$ and the second one $A=\frac{By}{1-B+By}$...

Comment: Dear Jean Marie, Thank you, using your suggestion I solved it. yB/(1-B)=A(1-A), yB(1-A)=A(1-B), yB-yBA=A-AB, yB=A-AB+yBA, yB=A(1-B+yB), yB/(1-B+yB)=A

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Jean Marie, using your suggestion I solved it.

$\displaystyle \frac{yB}{(1-B)}=\frac{A}{(1-A)}$

$yB(1-A)=A(1-B)$

$yB-yBA=A-AB$

$yB=A-AB+yBA$

$yB=A(1-B+yB)$

$\displaystyle\frac {yB}{(1-B+yB)}\displaystyle=A$